# React-native Bridge is Nil when I call method from another method

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, react-native

but I have noticed that my bridge variable is nil whenever I call on it from another method. I believe this is because the bridge is only set when calling on a bridged method from javascript. I have tried everything from creating delegate to create a SingleTon class. None of the above work and I cannot figure out why it is only available in the method that I called from Javascript. Here is my class

Helper.h

```
#import "RCTBridge.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RCTEventEmitter.h"

@interface Helper : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule>

-(void) auth;

@end
```

Here is my .m file:
Helper.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Helper.h"
#import "RCTBridge.h"
#import "RCTEventDispatcher.h"

@implementation Helper
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

@synthesize bridge = _bridge;

- (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents {
  return @[@"SpotifyHelper"];
}


RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(auth)
{
  [self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendDeviceEventWithName:@"SpotifyHelper" body:@{@"Login": @true}];
  printf("Auth");
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(play:(NSString *) uri first: id)
{
  AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
  [appDelegate play:uri second:id];
}

@end
```

I call on that method from inside of my delegate like this:

```
[[AppDelegate alloc] init] auth]
```

Which is the reason I believe it is not initialized. I'm not sure how to get the RCTBridge variable to not be nil. Any help?

Answer (score 16):

The problem is here:

```
[[AppDelegate alloc] init] auth]
```

When you used the macro `RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()` React-Native will instantiate the class for you, and any subsequent `alloc/init`s will create new instances, unrelated the original. The bridge will not be instantiated in these new instances.

You can solve your problem by using NSNotifications.

Helper.h:

```
#import "RCTEventEmitter.h"

@interface Helper : RCTEventEmitter

+ (void)emitEventWithName:(NSString *)name andPayload:(NSDictionary *)payload;

@end
```

Helper.m:

```
#import "Helper.h"

@implementation Helper

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

- (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents {
  return @[@"SpotifyHelper"];
}

- (void)startObserving
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(emitEventInternal:)
                                               name:@"event-emitted"
                                             object:nil];
}

- (void)stopObserving
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)emitEventInternal:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  [self sendEventWithName:@"SpotifyHelper"
                     body:notification.userInfo];
}

+ (void)emitEventWithName:(NSString *)name andPayload:(NSDictionary *)payload
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"event-emitted"
                                                      object:self
                                                    userInfo:payload];
}

// Remaining methods

@end
```

There is a long discussion thread here: [What is the method can be used to send an event from native module to JS](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8714)

Answer (score 7):

Just to add onto oar.garuna's answer (which was just a complete life saver), for those who have more than one event and want to handle that, the following code will setup a single observer that we can then make a static call to `emitEventWithName` and the helper will handle it appropriately and send that event out.

eventHelper.h

```
@interface eventHelper : RCTEventEmitter

  + (void)emitEventWithName:(NSString *)name andPayload:(NSDictionary *)payload;

@end
```

eventHelper.m

```
@implementation eventHelper

  RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

  // The list of available events
  - (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents {
    return @[@"EventLoggedOut"];
  }

  // This function listens for the events we want to send out and will then pass the
  // payload over to the emitEventInternal function for sending to Javascript
  - (void)startObserving
  {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(emitEventInternal:)
                                             name:@"event-emitted"
                                           object:nil];
  }

  // This will stop listening if we require it
  - (void)stopObserving
  {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
  }

  // This will actually throw the event out to our Javascript
  - (void)emitEventInternal:(NSNotification *)notification
  {
    // We will receive the dictionary here - we now need to extract the name
    // and payload and throw the event
NSArray *eventDetails = [notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"detail"];
    NSString *eventName = [eventDetails objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDictionary *eventData = [eventDetails objectAtIndex:1];

    [self sendEventWithName:eventName
                   body:eventData];
  }

  // This is our static function that we call from our code
  + (void)emitEventWithName:(NSString *)name andPayload:(NSDictionary *)payload
  {
    // userInfo requires a dictionary so we wrap out name and payload into an array and stick
    // that into the dictionary with a key of 'detail'
    NSDictionary *eventDetail = @{@"detail":@[name,payload]};
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"event-emitted"
                                                    object:self
                                                  userInfo:eventDetail];
  }

@end
```

Once that part has been setup you should then be able to make a call to our static function `emitEventWithName` from wherever as follows:

```
[eventHelper emitEventWithName:@"myEventName" andPayload:@{@"key":@"value1"}];
```

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: Where do you call the startObserving method?

Comment: @FernandoCaride The `startObserving` and `stopObserving` functions are overrides from the RCTEventEmitter class that is implemented in the .h file. So these should be called automatically when your app starts and the class is instantiated. (Hope that makes sense!)