# Can I instantiate a ViewController, and await completion of tasks a few ViewControllers down the line before continuing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm working on integrating an existing iOS application into React-Native, the friend I'm helping is insistent on using their existing custom UIViewControllers with as little modification as possible.

The goal is:

`react-native -> (objc vc1)find bluetooth camera -> (objc vc2)send wifi information to camera -> (objc vc3)connect to camera -> (objc vc3)return data -> return to react-native root controller`

I've got the hardware successfully connecting.

So, in my bridge, I'm exporting this method which when called in js opens the native view controller:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(changeToBluetoothView)
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    AddDeviceBLEInitViewController *vc = (AddDeviceBLEInitViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddDeviceBLEInitViewController"];
    appDelegate.window.rootViewController = vc;
  });
}
```

In which the next view controllers in instantiated etc...

What I need to do is wait for the user to finish connecting the camera, return the data, and continue the execution of my react project, but I can't for the life of me think of an elegant way to do it. Can I use `RCT_REMAP_METHOD` and promises to await completion of vc3?

Is there a way to nest callbacks that are completed upon success of each stage that finally returns to the method call, which in turn continues the execution of the react code?

Comment: Do you need to use React-Native?  From my experience I'd try to avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: That's my experience as well, but yea :/

Really though, if I can find a way to have a call back in the initial function that completes after a method is called several steps down the process I'll be set - the actual react integration is ok.

Comment: Nice to hear we think alike.  I hope you sort it out quickly and in an easy way.  Good luck Rej!

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using `RCTEventEmitter` to solve this problem.

I made a class method that emitted an event, which I then called from my final view controller.

This thread ound up being very helpful, and other than some minor changes it was correct almost verbatim:

[Using RCTEventEmiitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38818287/react-native-bridge-is-nil-when-i-call-method-from-another-method)